# How can I read data from a Realm Query in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a User query with data and I want to retrive the data inside it, but I can't do it, in the console log all it says me is this ,, StandaloneCoroutine{Completed}@55d57e3 "

I want to retrive the data and then make operations on it, can anyone help??
I tried other solutions but nothing worked....

**UPDATE**

So I changed to a Realm List but I cant access the elements inside the User query, how can I do that?

```
class User: RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
var email: String = ""
var password: String = ""
var code: String = ""
```

}

```
override val getUsers: Flow<RealmList<User>>
    get() = realm.query<User>()
        .find()
        .asFlow()
        .map {results->
        results.list.toRealmList()
    }
```

Comment: Use [RealmList](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/io.realm.kotlin.types/-realm-list/index.html) not List. However, [.find](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/io.realm.kotlin.query/find.html) returns a [RealmResults](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/io.realm.kotlin.query/-realm-results/index.html) object so the return from function is not defined correctly.

Comment: What is this API? This doesn't look like regular Realm APIs. Without knowing where these extension functions came from and what they are, it is impossible to answer this question.... especially knowing that even based on the code snippet, Realm is being fundamentally misused at least.

Comment: ok but can you at least give me an api or a function with which I can access the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer kind of depends on what the use case is - but there are several issues with the code in the question.

In general, when working  with Realm, best practice is to use [RealmList](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/io.realm.kotlin.types/-realm-list/index.html) instead of Kotlin List. It works similar but provides a Realm layer to interact with objects.

However, it doesn't appear you working with either based on the return.

There's a query with a [.find](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/io.realm.kotlin.query/find.html) and that process will actually return a [RealmResults](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/io.realm.kotlin.query/-realm-results/index.html) object (which is immutable by the way) which is then what you should be returning from the function.

Comment: Ok, but how can I access the data inside that RealmResults object

Comment: @Mihneas22 You can query and iterate through a RealmList property as you would a Kotlin List. A for loop for example: `for (dog in dogsRealmResults) {` or `dogRealmResults.forEach { dog -->`. You can also filter/query on results as well to get more fine-grained results.